# What LayoutManager can match the height of a JLabel or a JTextField to the size of its font?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have several `JPanel`s with which contain `JLabel`s and `JTextField`s for user input in my Swing application.

I am hand-editing the code generated by the NetBeans GUI Builder, but still want to maintain a similar layout.

I started by using a `GridLayout`. I can tweak the `hgap` to make my `JLabel`s and `JTextField`s the right size, but I will have to do this individually for all of the `JPanel`s.

Is there a standard `LayoutManager` which will calculate the correct height of a text component based on the component's font size and pad the containing component with space in between and/or around the text components?

**Edit:**

As requested, here is an SSCCE to demonstrate what I am trying to do

GridLayoutSSCCE:

```
package gridlayoutsscce;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class GridLayoutSSCCE {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Grid Layout SSCCE");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.add(new GridLayoutSSCCEPanel());
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

GridLayoutSSCCEPanel:

```
package gridlayoutsscce;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class GridLayoutSSCCEPanel extends JPanel {
    public GridLayoutSSCCEPanel() {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        this.add(new JLabel("Label 1:"));
        this.add(new JTextField());

        this.add(new JLabel("Label 2:"));
        this.add(new JTextField());
    }
}
```

This looks fine when I first run the program. However, when I resize the window, the text fields stretch out so each fills half of the height of the window. I want them to remain the same height that they were originally when the window resizes.

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that uses `GridLayout` and calls `pack()` on the enclosing window.

Comment: +1 For [sscce](http://sscce.org/) and additional explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) will do what you want, although it is highly flexible, it also consider one of the most complex.

I'm sure `MigLayout` will get a mention, but I've never personally used it, and I should also mention [JGoodies `FormLayout`](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/libraries/forms/), but again, I've never used it.

Comment: Based on the updated question, I'd also consider `BoxLayout`; previously up-voted.

Comment: I've used GridBagLayout before. I forgot about GridBagConstraints.fill. It will take a bit of work just to be able to use that.

Comment: @Code-Guru No one said it would be easy ;)

Comment: It looks like GridBagLayout fits the bill. I have to add a lot of code to do what I want, though ;-(

Comment: @Code-Guru You could probably construct a series of helpers to make it easier, things like `add(Component, Container, x, y)` for example.  Internally, it would set up the required constraints for you. You could even seed it with common values (such as `Insests`)

Answer (score 1):

Friends don't let friends use GridBagLayout (we're all friends here, right?)

Using JGoodies forms layout, this does what you say you want your SSCCE to do:

```
class MyFormLayoutSSCCEPanel extends JPanel {
  public MyFormLayoutSSCCEPanel() {
    FormLayout layout = new FormLayout(
      "pref, pref:grow",   // columns
      "pref, pref");       // rows
    this.setLayout(layout);

    CellConstraints cc = new CellConstraints();
    this.add(new JLabel("Label 1:"), cc.xy(1,1));
    this.add(new JTextField(), cc.xy(2, 1));

    this.add(new JLabel("Label 2:"), cc.xy(1, 2));
    this.add(new JTextField(), cc.xy(2, 2));
  }
}
```

(Note that this doesn't reproduce the behaviour of your original SSCCE *exactly* though - I've told it to grow the text fields horizontally to eat all available space.)

I don't recommend swapping to JGoodies yet though - you need at least a couple of weeks of time-wasting frustration with the default Swing layout managers before you can properly appreciate the kind of effort that JGoodies formlayout will save you.

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. "(Note that this doesn't reproduce the behaviour of your original SSCCE exactly though - I've told it to grow the text fields horizontally to eat all available space.)" This is probably a good feature, one that I have had in the back of my mind while working on this project in fact. And I've worked with the default Swing layout managers quite a bit. It's just been a long, long time. I will certainly look into JGoodies, although probably not for this current project.